# SegFault when calling function in asm

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, arm

I started to learn calling a function in assembly. I followed much tutorial in the internet and make some modification to it.

But it doesnot really work as expected.

```
.data
 hello:  .ascii "hello everyone\n"
 len= . - hello
 .text

.global _start

exit:
       mov %r1,#0
       mov %r2,#0
       mov %r0, #0
       mov %r7, #1
       swi #0

println:
        mov %r7, #4
        swi #0
        mov %pc, %lr
        bx %r7
_start:
        ldr %r1, =hello
        ldr %r2, =len
        b println
        b exit
```

and the output goes

```
hello everyone
Segmentation fault
```

I dont know where i was wrong.

Comment: For what platform is this code?

Comment: @ThomasJager: 32-bit ARM, with Linux system calls, as you can see from the tags.  Using `%` decorators on register names is unusual, but apparently supported: `arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostdlib arm.s` assembles + links it into a binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For function calls, use the `bl` (branch and link) instruction.  This sets up `lr` to contain the return address.  Your code uses `b` (branch)  rather than `bl`, so `lr` is not set up and returning from `println` goes to an unpredictable address, likely crashing your program.

To fix this, use `bl` instead of `b` for function calls:

```
    bl println
    bl exit
```